# How can I filter questions based on tags?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know two types of logic filter. Like:

1. `[Tag1] [Tag2]`:  Tag1 && Tag2
2. `[Tag1] or [Tag2]` Tag1 || Tag2

Are there more patterns or advanced filter logical searches?

Comment: The not operator: `[tag1] -[tag2]`

Comment: What else are you hoping for?

Comment: We have [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in the help center. If you have a specific question not answered there, feel free to ask it, but I don't know what you want.

Comment: Tags support wildcard `*` usage in search. Eg. Search all python versions by searching [`[python-*.*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-*.*).